# How to obtain the effect of linebreak with xelatex?

Tags: xetex, luatex, texpad, chinese

Now I use TexPadtex to compile my tex files for the real time preview feature. Unfortunately it doesn't support xelatex or lualatex engine. So I have some trouble when I compile a Chinese document. The TexPadtex typesetter or CJK package doesn't support Chinese line break well. I can't include xeCJK package for lacking support of the TexPadtex engine.

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{CJKutf8,CJKnumb,CJKspace,amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}

\frame{

\begin{proof}[证明]
因为\(u_n\)都在\(x_0\)处连续, 所以\(S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n u_k\)也在\(x_0\)处连续,          又\(S_n \rightrightarrows S\), 故\(S\)在\(x_0\)处连续.
\end{proof}


}


\end{CJK}

\end{document}
```

[image: The effect of CJK package]
The effect of ctex compiling via xelatex looks nice.

```
\documentclass{ctexbeamer}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}


\frame{

\begin{proof}[证明]
因为\(u_n\)都在\(x_0\)处连续, 所以\(S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n u_k\)也在\(x_0\)处连续, 又\(S_n \rightrightarrows S\), 故\(S\)在\(x_0\)处连续.
\end{proof}


}


\end{document}
```

[image: The effect of xeCJK package]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Mico Please check the title.

Comment: Are you using the iOS version? The Mac version supposedly supports other TeX engines: https://www.texpad.com/osx

Comment: The title and body of your title seem to be connected only loosely. That's why I asked you to clarify your objective. Sorry to have annoyed you with this request.

Comment: @RalfStubner No, I use the Mac version. But I need the TexPadtex typesetter rather  than external typesetter for the much faster real time preview feature.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.